# Reaching video part of IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, mobile

I have an app made in Unity and I have problems with reaching videos in IOS. (There is no problem with Android). By the videos I mean the one at photos app that comes with IOS. Do you know how can I reach videos ? I will publish the code if necessary.

Comment: Have you set the read permissions to access the photos?

Comment: Yes but the problem is I want to access directly to videos folder, not photos, and I can't do it. I imported UnityNativeGallery to my app.

Comment: Is videos folder different from photos gallery? I thought it’s the same?